# Add Relying Party Trust is failing in ADFS SAML

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I've spent quite a few hours fighting with these issues so I though a quick recap might be helpful for somebody else too.

Answer (score 5):

First, when trying to import an RP from a metadata URL:

[image]

I was getting this error:

```
An error occured during an attempt to read the federation metadata. Verify that the specified URL or hostname is a valid federation metadata endpoint.
...
Error message: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send.
```

[image]

The problem turned out to be caused by the fact that Windows Server at least up to 2016 is using TLS 1.0 for .NET framework (in which the ADFS configuration wizard is implemented) while my service hosting the metadata document only allowed TLS 1.2 as the minimum version:

[image]

Dropping the minimum version to TLS 1.0 is a no-go from security point of view, so the proper fix would be to [enable TLS 1.2 as the default version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client#configure-for-strong-cryptography) on the ADFS server.

That would solve the issue (which I confirmed with a test) but then some of the other RPs only supporting TLS 1.0 would stop working, so I had to give up on importing metadata directly from a URL and use the file import option:

[image]

In this case another error popped up, which happened to be:

```
An error occured during an attempt to read the federation metadata. Verify that the specified URL or hostname is a valid federation metadata endpoint.
...
Error message: Entity descriptor '...'. ID6018: Digest verification failed for reference '...'.
```

This one turned out to be caused by me when I formatted the XML in the metadata file with line breaks and tabs to improve readability - it's all on a single line originally. ADFS won't allow that so the document must be exactly the same it came out of the metadata endpoint.

The same issue might result in different error messages and codes, depending on Windows and ADFS versions. For example this one is possible caused by a failed metadata integrity check as well:

```
An error occured during an attempt to read the federation metadata. Verify that the specified URL or hostname is a valid federation metadata endpoint.
...
Error message: Entity descriptor '...'. ID6013: The signature verification failed.
```

After having successfully imported a raw metadata file and having added a suitable Claim Issuance Policy I've got it finally working:

[image]